# Scroll event in AngularJS only fired when scrolling off the top or bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scroll, angularjs-directive

I've been banging my head on this one for a while.....

No clue why this is happening, but my

```
          angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            console.log($window.scrollY);
            scope.$apply();
          });
```

function is only firing when i scroll off the page. (See Pictures)

[image]

[image]

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Does this happen only in Safari? Could you also isolate the problem and post it in a plunker?

Comment: What are the width and height of your html and body tags? Are they positioned absolutely or relatively?

Comment: I can't isolate it in plunkr but here is the url with the code: http://abc.morado.xyz:32982/#/index. This only appears to fire in Safari.

Comment: @plondon the body is positioned relatively with min-height of 100%